# is Netifi client library available for languages other than java

Tags: spring, kubernetes, reactive, rsocket, netifi

I am building micro services based on Rsocket. Analysing load balancing and cloud support and found as its persistent connection, k8 cannot do load balance for client requests out of the box but only for  client connection. So only options to use either client side load balancing or use rsocket broker like Netifi which act as routing gateway.

As micro services is polyglot, I want to know if Netifi client library is implemented for different languages like c++, .net, go etc?